Is it safe to assume that any hybrid algorithm can be transformed into a purely quantum form with comparable complexity?
Suppose we have a definite function of interest from numbers to numbers (from a finite set).
In general, we have a lot of options when we construct algorithms that compute it (with some errors, possibly). We can use classical processing, randomization, quantum tools such as oracles, measurements (in multiple rounds), quantum channels and any combinations of those.
But as an input for quantum algorithms we usually require oracles which are just quantum unitaries, i.e. purely quantum algorithms. So, can we assume that any hybrid algorithm can be transformed into an oracle with a comparable complexity?
If we have just a deterministic classical algorithm then the conversion is possible, this is well known. But I'm not sure about that if we're allowed to use multiple rounds of quantum measurements additionally.

what result are you thinking about when you write "this is well known"? Do you just mean that any classical (deterministic) operation can be implemented as a unitary operation? More generally, how would you consider Shor's algorithm as requiring an oracle? Aren't "oracles" (in this context) generally just ways to say "a unitary implementing this classical operation that I know can be done efficiently but don't want to bother with in the analysis"?

Yes, any classical deterministic operation can be done as a unitary.
The example I had in mind is Grover's algorithm where the oracle is a white box, so we know it. Is it possible to transform the whole routine (let's say we have the harder case where we don't know the number of solutions) into an application of a single unitary, which becomes an oracle that outputs the solution (instead of answering yes/no)?

isn't that already what the algorithm is? Or do you mean to also somehow encode the post-processing you'd perform on the outcome probabilities (essentially performing some kind of majority rule in this case) into the unitary? But to some degree you always necessarily are going to perform some kind of such post-processing, as that's how you "give meaning" to the measurement outcomes. But are you thinking of Grover's as a "hybrid algorithm"? In which case, what do you mean by "hybrid" here? Because Grover's seems like a pretty straightforward "just quantum" algorithm to me

It's not obvious how to transform a majority voting after series of measurements into a single unitary.

well, maybe it's trivial, but if you run the same unitary in parallel $N$ times, then you can define an estimator that takes the sequence of outcomes (which in this case is essentially "a single outcome") and gives back the outcome that occurred most often, and you thus implement majority voting. That's just another way to see what standard majority voting would be. Of course, this is still doing post-processing after the unitary, but that's kinda my point: some modicum of post-processing is always going to happen, otherwise how do you interpret measurement results to mean anything?
